# How to take union of sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, field-theory

As a homework assignment, I have been asked to provide a concrete example for why the countable union of sigma algebras is not always a sigma algebra.

The example that I had thought of was to take the sigma algebras of singletons over the natural numbers. i.e. $\mathscr A_i = \bigl\{\{i\},\{i\}^c, \emptyset,\Bbb N \bigr\}$. Then for example, $\mathscr A_1 \bigcup \mathscr A_2$ would contain {1,2} but not its complement.

However, another student told me that this would not work because not only do you take the unions of the elements {i}, you also take the unions with $\{ \emptyset\}$ and $\{\Bbb N\}$, so the countably infinite union would contain the union $\{ \emptyset\}\bigcup\{ \emptyset\} \bigcup \{3\} \bigcup \{4\}\bigcup $... which would be the complement of the union {1,2}. Is this the correct way to take the unions of algebras?

Most of the examples I've seen online would just take the unions of the elements {i} and wouldn't consider the null in the unions. The logic the other student gave me seems correct, I just haven't seen this idea anywhere when reading about this topic. Can someone confirm or refute this?

Comment: Your notation has a mistake. You need ${\cal A}_i = \{ \{i\} ,\{i\}^c, \emptyset, \mathbb{N}\}$. This **is** a $\sigma$-algebra. Modulo notation, your example is a perfectly good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler example:

Consider the space $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$, and let $\Sigma_1 = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, \Omega \}$ and
$\Sigma_2 = \{ \emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{3\}, \Omega \}$.

Both are $\sigma$-algebras, but $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ is not as it would have to contain the set $\{1,3\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Most of the examples that I saw on this website were like this. I think my question is more like: what exactly does it mean to take the union of two algebras? Is it all of the permutations of unions of the elements listed between each sigma-algebra?

Comment: No, it literally means the union.

Comment: Okay, I think I am still confused. I understand how to take unions and intersections of sets, but I've never worked with fields/algebras before. I think I need someone to explain to me what it means to take the union of two fields. So in your example, could you spell out what Σ1∪Σ2 would equal?  Would it be {∅,{1},{3},{2,3},{1,2},Ω}?

Comment: @Kaytee: Yes, it is just all the elements of both sets with (customarily but optionally) the duplicates removed. It is no different to $\{1,2\} \cup \{1, 3\} = \{1 ,2 ,3 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of $\mathcal A_1,\mathcal A_2$ is a very valid example.[Assuming that countable collection of sigma algebra also includes finite collections].  But your argument is no right. It is not true that $\{1,2\}$ is in $\mathcal A_1 \cup\mathcal A_2$. What is true is $\{1\}^{c}$ and $\{2\}^{c}$  are in $\mathcal A_1 \cup\mathcal A_2$ but their intersection is not in this union. I don't see any point in your friends objection.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Why does it matter that the intersection is not in the union?

Comment: Never mind, I realized the answer to my own question. It's because sigma fields are closed under union and intersection.